az role assignment delete: The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider
I'm trying to do some cleanup (to solve other issues) within a yaml, and I've come up with this:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'MYSUBSCRIPTION'
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az role assignment delete --ids "GUID1 GUID2 GUIDn"
      name: CleanupRoleAssignments

And I'm getting this error:
ERROR: (MissingSubscription) The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider.
Code: MissingSubscription
Message: The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider.

I tried adding --scope but that only got me an additional warning WARNING: option '--scope' will be ignored due to use of '--ids'. The error persisted.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?
TIA
Jim

Try below in local pc: Replace with your own subscription and resource group
az role assignment list --scope /subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/wb-test-rg

will return like
[
  {
    "condition": null,
    "conditionVersion": null,
    "createdBy": "492b05b3-bc6c-4497-8d3e-ab42366d3b9a",
    "createdOn": "2024-06-06T08:33:53.807218+00:00",
    "delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId": null,
    "description": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/wb-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/454c98bf-349a-4643-8f41-8bf45293440e",
    "...."
  }
]


then delete the assignment using the id:
az role assignment delete --ids "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/wb-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/454c98bf-349a-4643-8f41-8bf45293440e"


Thanks! That's more or less what I ended up doing with powershell. I'll post it below.

You just need to delete the leading "/" and leave
--scope "subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>


The --ids parameter expects resource IDs for the role assignments. This is what it should look like for a resource-specific assignment:
/subscriptions/5ef3ad25-ad2f-4fbd-846c-e0de974adf45/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/mycognitiveaccount/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/c89f4724-986a-47ca-9f1b-2c152a6b5a73

For assignments at subscription or resource group level, some of the parts of that ID would be left out.
The idea is that the ID identifies where the role assignment is as well as the assignment ID.

THAT WAS AN EYE OPENER THANKS. My role assignment in directly on resource group level, so I guess the ID would be something like: /subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/MY_RG/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/ROLE_ASSIGNEMENT_ID . I'll give it a try right now.

Hmmm it's giving me "ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'" now.

@JimAndrakakis, you can try to use the command "az role assignment list --all" to list all the assignments, from the returned JSON result, you can get the correct id and other information of each role assignment.

Thank you both @juunas and @wenbo. What I ended up doing is this:
$iacDescription = 'IaC generated role assignment'

Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
$json = & az role assignment list --resource-group 'MYRESOURCEGROUP'

$roleAssignmentList = ($json | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Write-Host "Count = $($roleAssignmentList.Count)"

$idList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($roleAssignment in $roleAssignmentList) {                
  if ($roleAssignment.description -eq $iacDescription) {
    Write-Host "roleDefinitionName = $($roleAssignment.roleDefinitionName), description = $($roleAssignment.description), id = $($roleAssignment.id)"
    $idList.Add($roleAssignment.id) | Out-Null
  }
}
if ($idList.Count -gt 0) {
  Write-Host "Cleaning up:`n$idList"
  az role assignment delete --ids $idList
}
else {
  Write-Host "Nothing to clean"
}

